Story - the main characters name is Caterwaul (may be a different spelling)
It's a fantasy story in the Might and Magic style. The character is a male Indigenous/Native style person. They can leap very high in the air. A notable part of the tale is them leaping 25 feet to the top of a wooden structure. They wield and throw tomahawks with great accuracy. At one point in the story they fight a wizard who is torn in half and sheds his skin after being hit by a bolt of lightning (magic style spell, not nature based)
The author lived near London, Ontario, Canada around 1991. The book would have been published sometime after 1991.
I know it's a hail mary, it's just a pivotal memory of my life. The author was a camp council in 1991 at Camp Wymawakka (not exact spelling)  He told us this entire novel verbally from memory and was going to publish it shortly afterwards. Our group of 10-11 year-olds were mesmerized. It made an impossibly large impact on young me and started a lifelong joy of storytelling. He had a group of young kids sitting still and attentive for 3 hours. If I could locate this story, or the author I would be eternally grateful.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How long was this story?  5 minutes, half an hour?

3 hours at least. Told over the course of a couple days at camp.

Was the author male or female? Ican think of a couple of Canadian authors who would write stories like that from around that time.

From what you say, it is possibly that the story was never published. Maybe contact the camp and ask for the names of camp councils in 1991?

The author was male @Spencer

I have also tried tracking down any info on Camp with no luck so far. The camp name must have changed since the 1990's. Doesn't help I only know how it's spelled from memory which could be off slightly. It's phonetically Wym-a-wa-ka. I'm going to keep trying to track it down though. Good suggestion.

Please edit that detail into your question.

Edited to add the character is male. Thanks Spencer.

Where in CA is the camp located? That might help in tracking it down and, therefore, finding the owners/managers from the early 90s who might be able to help locate the counselor/author.

The camp was located between 20-40 mins drive of London Ontario. We took a bus there so I'm not sure which direction we travelled.
